# Failed to load driver! (wifi rt18192cu usb)

Tags: android, wifi

my android device use rtl8192cu usb wifi. I have insmod 8192cu.ko, cfg80211.ko, rfkill.ko.
when i open wifi, the logcat show me:

```
01-02 00:01:06.660 E/WifiStateMachine( 2297): Failed to load driver! 
01-02 00:01:06.660 E/WifiStateMachine( 2297): DriverFailedState
```

So does anyone know why the driver is loaded but would wrong ?

Beginning an error：

1. 8192cu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_scan_done (err 0)
2. 8192cu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_remain_on_channel_expired (err 0)
3. 8192cu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_new_sta (err 0)
4. 8192cu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_disconnected (err 0)
5. .......

So i load driver 8192cu.ko, cfg80211.ko and rfkill.ko, but it's also tell me wrong.

Comment: you wifi is not working ?

Comment: yes, I can't open wifi. Always stay in “Turning Wi-Fi on....”

Comment: Have you tried restarting the device ? Is your device rooted ?

Comment: Already reboot my device, not rooted.

Comment: if is still in warranty you should go to a service to see what is wrong. Otherwise I could recommend you to do a factory reset !

Answer (score 0):

I think you had the airplane mode activated.

So, go to the settings/wireless&networks 
and ensure that the airplane mode is not activated.

Comment: and restart the emulator or device

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the kernel modules in the correct order.
Try to load the cfg80211.ko file first, followed by the rfkill and then the 8192cu.ko.